# What's the use of this statement: { router: routerReducer }

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I know its an easy question, but am a beginner.

What is the use of this line in `combineReducer`

```
router: routerReducer
```

The line is in this context:

```
export default combineReducers({
  article,
  articleList,
  auth,
  router: routerReducer
});
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: It's not a statement. It's an object literal property.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it should be the clearest line because you're defining an object, a key and value pairs collection. In fact, your code is equivalent to:

```
export default combineReducers({
  article: article,
  articleList: articleList,
  auth: auth,
  router: routerReducer
});
```

thanks to an ES6 feature

Answer (score 0):

The code is passing a javascript object to the `combineReducers()` function. There are 2 ways to add elements to the object:

```
{item: item}
```

and

```
{item}
```

while the latter is a shorthand for the first one. The shorthand only works if object key and variable name are the same.

The code could have also been written like this:

```
{
  article: article,
  articleList: articleList,
  auth: auth,
  router: routerReducer
}
```